# simple Inheritance issue

Tags: python, inheritance, scrapy

I have a problem with inheritance. Probably a beginners mistake. I made two Scrapy spiders:

```
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class SchemaorgSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'schemaorg'

    def parse(self, response):
        print "parse"
        ...
```

and

```
from schemaorg import SchemaorgSpider
class SchemaorgSpider_two(SchemaorgSpider):
    name = 'schemaorg_two'
    sitemap_urls = [
        urltoparse    
    ]

    sitemap_rules= [('/stuff/','parse_fromrule')]    

    def parse_fromrule(self, response):
        print "parsefromrule"
        self.parse(response)
```

I am basically defining all the logic in mparse and then using it in all child classes. When I run my second spider, I see only "parsefromrule" and not "parse". This looks to me like "inheritance 101" but it does not work. 
What's wrong with it?
edit: test without scrapy that works:

```
class a(object):
    def aa(self):
        print "hello"

class b(a):
    def bb(self):
        self.aa()
class c(b):
    def cc(self):
        self.aa()

hello = c()
hello.cc()
hello.bb()
hello.aa()
```

I see all 3 "hello". I am confused why it doesn't work with Scrapy.

Edit2: if I put self.blabla(response) instead of self.parse(response) I get an error. It means that it is looking for an existing method.

Comment: Your code snippet (when stripped of scrappy stuff) doesn't reproduce the problem. Please post a  mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce it with a mcve example. I tried a simpole class A...class B(A) example and it works. I was hoping it was a simple inheritance problem about visibility.